# Does android.intent.action.DATE_CHANGED work properly on all devices at least when time or date is not changed manually?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I know this Question has been asked before. I have researched quiet a bit and the alternative is to use AlarmManager.
But this is not what I want since my app requires to run a certain piece of code at 00:00 EVERY DAY.
Currently I am using an Accessibility service and the service may continue for more than a day resulting in alarm not getting triggered on the second day at 00:00.

android.intent.action.DATE_CHANGED would have been been perfect but apparently there are a lot of bugs.I cant help but wonder why google wouldn't rectify something as important as this.

Any workArounds would be very helpful and well appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You could use the AlarmManager and schedule for the next 00:00, when it triggers it can re schedule the process for the next day.

Comment: Yes I thought of that..if somehow the app were to crash,it would break the cycle right? The alarm would never again be received right ?

Comment: i wanted a fail-safe method for this

Comment: @abhilashpoojary the schedule is managed by the OS and is the best guarantee you can have. I've just noticed there is a setRepeating. There are mechanism in place to work around powered off devices and such.

[link]http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

Comment: @liloargana.You are correct.I already found the solution.SetRepeating works just fine.Thanks anyway:)